# Return an associated field based on an aggr() answer?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

So I have this problem that we want to find out per shift which machine started working last. I.e. which machine is the last to register a load. So this

```
max(aggr(min({<ACTIVITY={'Loading'}>}[RECORD START TIME]),
       [CYCLE RECORD SHIFT],[CYCLE PRIMARY MACHINE]))
```

gives me the correct time but now I want to be able to return the machine name as well.

Here is a sample of data

```
load * inline [
ACTIVITY,CYCLE PRIMARY MACHINE,CYCLE RECORD SHIFT,CYCLE SHIFT START TIME,RECORD START TIME
Loading,DT90015,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 11:45:17
Loading,DT90015,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 12:02:14
Loading,DT90015,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 12:21:32
Loading,DT90023,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 08:12:48
Loading,DT90023,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 08:50:43
Loading,DT90023,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 09:17:27
Loading,DT90023,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 09:53:19
Loading,DT90023,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 11:51:52
Loading,DT90023,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 12:07:09
Loading,DT90023,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 12:29:23
Loading,DT90024,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 08:08:54
Loading,DT90024,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 08:24:51
Loading,DT90024,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 08:40:15
Loading,DT90024,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 09:02:07
Loading,DT90024,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 09:25:59
Loading,DT90024,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 09:57:36
Loading,DT90024,2016/02/25.0,25/02/2016 07:00:00,25/02/2016 12:37:09
];
```

Thanks Eldad for the suggestion but that returns this:

[image: Per shift performance]

I should probably have included the table I want to create in my original question

Comment: You never said you are using a table. My solution works just fine when used as a stand alone.
what is the logic in using a table with "CYCLE SHIFT START TIME" with the your aggregation on "CYCLE RECORD SHIFT"? you are basically showing the raw data...
Please show an example of expected output

Comment: Agreed it does look odd. They are equivalent levels of granularity. But the SHIFT START TIME is easier for the users to read and the CYCLE RECORD SHIFT feels more comfortable to me. IT will work either way. The example is that table. I want to know for each shift which machine stated last. Ideally I would like to be able to count how many times each machine was last, but If I can't display it I can't think how I could count it either, so this is a first step. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay,
So [here](http://www.upfile.co.il/file/56041229.html) is a working solution,
Basically in your script you need to create another aggragated table like

```
LastMachine:
Load [CYCLE RECORD SHIFT], max([RECORD START TIME]) as max_ts Resident Data group by [CYCLE RECORD SHIFT];
left join
Load [CYCLE RECORD SHIFT],[RECORD START TIME] as max_ts, [CYCLE PRIMARY MACHINE] as Last_Machine Resident Data;
```

and then you get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new variable "vMax" and assign it

```
=Timestamp(max(aggr(min({<ACTIVITY={'Loading'}>}[RECORD START TIME]),
   [CYCLE RECORD SHIFT],[CYCLE PRIMARY MACHINE])) )
```

Then use this calc to get the machine name:

```
=MaxString({<[RECORD START TIME]={'$(vMax)'}>}[CYCLE PRIMARY MACHINE])
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only returns the global last machine. I can't use it in a table that tracks performance over time or ideally counts how many times each machine has been the last to start.

Comment: you did not mention the expected output format. This solution is correct for your original question...please mark it as so.
I will try to answer your later question once you post an example

Comment: I have edited the question, but your answer was helpful. Thanks

Comment: I posted a new solution. check it out.